# How to configure Prettier to keep property on the same line as jsx element?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier formats code like this:

```
<button
  className="prettier-class"
  id="prettier-id"
  onClick={this.handleClick}>
  Click Here
</button>
```

I want it to format it like this:

```
<button className="prettier-class"
        id="prettier-id"
        onClick={this.handleClick}>
  Click Here
</button>
```

Is there a setting for this?

Comment: You can probably increase the `printWidth` setting in prettier to 120. (Default is 80). 

Doing so will keep your `JSX` and property on the same line. 
But it will keep all the props on the sameline.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but if it decides to wrap properties, it starts doing this from new line. I do not mind, but linter does. =)